# Unable to get Socket to receive packets

Tags: python

I'm trying to send a message from Client to Server using socket. For some reason, the message is not received. example: the client sends 'myname_0' the server needs to receive it and decode it and continue further.

Listener:

```
import socket

class SocketSender():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket()
        ip = socket.gethostname()  # IP to server.
        port = 7000
        self.sock.bind((ip, port))
        print("Binding successful.")
        self.sock.listen(2)
        print("Listening....")
    self.listening = True
    # self.sock.connect((ip, port))
    # print("Connected.")


def sendpacket(self, packet):
    self.sock.send(packet.encode())

def receivepacket(self):
    while self.listening:
        con, addr = self.sock.accept()
        print("Receiving packet from " + str(addr))

        packet = self.sock.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        return str(packet)
```

Sender:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
ip = socket.gethostname()
port = 7000

sock.connect((ip, port))
print("connection to " + ip)
message = "test_0"
sock.send(message.encode("utf-8"))
```

When run:

```
import GUI
import SocketSender

# Entry: 0, Exit: 1
gui = GUI.ASGui()

# gui.run()
socket = SocketSender.SocketSender()

id = input()

while 1 == 1:
    packet = socket.receivepacket()
    name, state = packet.split("_")
    break

if state == 0:
    print("Welcome back, " + name)
else:
    if state == 1:
        print("Goodbye, " + name)
```

I do get the outputs Listening and  Binded. But I am unable to receive a message. Help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please check if indentation is good in Listener. Second, when do You run Sender?

Comment: Can you sniff it with Wireshark and see if the packet is sent/ received in your computer?